# MacOS Catalina Verifying app at bootstrap

Tags: applications, catalina, verify

I updated to Catalina yesterday and now I have the following message:

[image]

every time I turn on my macbook. Until it finishes, I can't open any app.

I've already tried:

```bsh
sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Docker.app
```

and the output is:

```bsh
xattr: /Applications/Docker.app: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine
```

I have the same problems with other apps like Xcode, Spotify, iOS runtime 11.0 and so on.

I've never encountered this error before.
Should I just wait an hotfix by Apple or do we have a workaround for it?

**Update:**

I contacted the Apple Support and they suggested me to perform a first aid on the HD and re-install the OS. Both didn't work.

#### Temporary workaround

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250735975?answerId=251529672022#251529672022

(This reduces the security of macOS so it's just temporary)

Comment: Same here. It's been happening since the beta. I left a feedback in the Feedback Assistant app but I haven't received an answer yet.

Comment: I have the same problem. Each time I turn on my Mac with Catalina, it starts working without any reason (gets hot and high fans), and starts verifying apps at random. If I open some apps, they keep bouncing until the verification process has come to an end for all them. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Stefano, not yet. I contacted the Apple Support and they asked me to submit a sysdiagnose. I'm still waiting the Engineers to reach me out.

Answer (score 1):

I also met the similar problem. I contacted Apple technical support and got the reply that I should try [Reset NVRAM or PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) or [RESET SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295). But It does not work at all.

Finally I erased the disk, reinstalled macOS Catalina and then recovered important data from Time Machine and other backups. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Comment: Hi Yun, thank you for sharing your experience. I've just tried it and it doesn't work unfortunately. Does it work to you ?

Comment: It does not work at all. Finally I erased the disk, reinstalled macOS Catalina and then recovered important data from Time Machine and other backups. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904