# Tiny pop up window with a bar loading up randomly appears. Symbol: Grey house with a circle in it

Tags: mac, finder

For the last couple of weeks I have this thing happening where every once in a while a tiny window will pop up with a bar that is loading and it says something like "Checking...". I can close the pop up or it will disappear once the bar loaded completely. It looks very sketchy that's why I am asking what this could be. I have not been able to find anything on the net. Also, next to the bar there is a symbol of a grey or silver house with a circle in it.[image: pic]

Can you guys please enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: That's the Google Backup and Sync icon.  It's probably doing an application update.

Comment: Okay. That would be fine. I have this with other applications as well. Isn't it kinda sketchy to have an update creep up o you like this? Sometimes it does not even mention the name of the app.

Comment: @JanGogoll I found Google products (like Chrome and Google Drive) are pretty secretive about updates it does in the background, and are big drain on the performance of the Mac, that's why I switched to other products.

Answer (score 1):

This specific window is actually the macOS application verification process, which is slightly different than Gatekeeper.

Here's some more info which may help describe what it's doing:

Apple's explanation of Gatekeeper can be found here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491

A high-level overview of problems with Catalina's application verification process can be found here: https://appletoolbox.com/why-is-macos-catalina-verifying-applications-before-i-can-open-them/

Catalina has had issues with this verification process, and random problems are not uncommon: [MacOS Catalina Verifying app at bootstrap](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371967/macos-catalina-verifying-app-at-bootstrap)

---

Regarding the process / application named "Backup & Sync from Google" - I've personally never heard of that, and after a very quick search online, it seemed that all roads seemed to point to an app which should be called "Google Drive"  I would probably investigate to make sure it's actually a legitimate application from Google.

---

The icon is the same icon you'll find in System Preferences under "Security & Privacy" - it's supposed to be a combination padlock wheel on a house:

[image: Security & Privacy]

Comment: "Google Backup and Sync" was the old name, it looks like they changed it to Google Drive recently.